# Bitmap, check if orthogonal path is closed

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 2d

An 2d array of bits are given.

```
var map1 = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
            [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
            [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0],
            [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
            [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
```

How I can programmaticaly check if some of the "ones" are forming a closed path ?

http://jsfiddle.net/RvN3k/

The two left bitmaps contains closed paths, the upper one is obvious, the lower one are simply a closed path with nothing inside.

The two right bitmaps doesn't contains closed paths, in the upper example one bit is missing, in the lower example the one diagonal pixel doesn't count, orthogonal paths only.

Answer (score 1):

Find a cell that holds a 1, then "flood" from there on. By this I mean: use a second map, all initially set to 0. When you encounter the first 1, set the cell in the second map to 1. Now check all adjacent cells, setting the cell in the second map to 1 if that in the original map is also 1. Once you try to set a cell that was already 1, you know you have encountered a closed path; do not check that cell again or you'll get an infinite loop.

EDIT: if you want a complete list of all cells connected to one cell by closed paths, juts add every cell you encounter during the "flooding" to a list that initially only holds the starting cell. If at some point you don't find another cell to flood, there is no closed path and you can throw away the list. Depending on whether you want the little "stubs" in your linked bitmaps to be considered part of the path or not, you'll have to do some branching, introducing new lists for each branch, merging them if they intersect.

Comment: I got the idea, but instead of making a secondary Map, I would use a list and save there the cordinates of found "ones", when I found a duplicate, the path is closed. Similar to Your approach, but more memory friendly I think. What's your opinion about this approach ?

Comment: Yeah you can do that as well, make sure to use something that lets you check for duplicates efficiently though.

Answer (score 1):

I've forked your fiddle and added a method findCycle().

```
var fill = function(map, x, y) {
    if (Math.min(x,y) >= 0 && Math.max(x,y) < mapSize && map[x][y] == 0) {
        map[x][y] = -1;
        for (var dx = -1; dx <=1; dx +=1) {
            for (var dy=-1; dy<=1; dy += 1) {
                fill(map, x+dx, y+dy);
            }
        }
    }
}

function detect(map) {
    for(var x = 0; x + 1 < mapSize; x++){
       for(var y = 0; y + 1 < mapSize; y++){
           if (map[x][y] == 0) {
               map[x][y] = -2;
               return;
           }
           else if (map[x][y]== 1 && map[x+1][y]==1 && map[x][y+1]== 1 && map[x+1][y+1]==1) {
               map[x][y] = -2;
               return;
           }
       }
    }
}

function findCycle(mapData) {
    for(var x = 0; x < mapSize; x++){
       for(var y = 0; y < mapSize; y++){
           if (mapData[x][y] == 0) {
               fill(mapData, x, y);
                detect(mapData);
               return;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

It finds the first 0. Recursively fills all adjacent 0's with "-1". Then searches for any still existing 0's that couldn't be reached from the initial 0. (while at the same time searching for a square of four "1" (red) squares.

http://jsfiddle.net/bn6pa/1/

A black square is drawn at the first point where it finds a cycle.

Comment: note in the fiddle it should be fill(mapData, x, y) not fill(mapData, 0, 0)

Comment: If you're still following this, I'd welcome comments on the fiddle [here], initially inspired by yours. I think the cpu complexity is somewhat better.

Comment: Hi Miquel. I don't think the complexity will be much faster (mine is O(n)). However mine uses recursion so will be slower than using a while loop. I could also blow the stack frame if it goes down too deap in the recursion. With your fiddle I didn't have time to look properly but perhaps try allowing diagonal moves too (if you don't already).

Comment: Thanks for checking :) You are doing diagonal moves when you fill, which is fine, since diagonal squares are connected. I'm avoiding them on purpose because the problem statement says connected walls are vertical or horizontal. I actually thought your algorithm was not going to be linear time! Let me look at it more carefully again, then. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
for each cell that's set to 1
    set that cell to -1
    recursively look for neighbouring cells set to 1, and set them to -1
        if you find a neighbouring cell that is already set to -1, loop found
    clean-up (set all cells that are set to -1 to 0, they are no longer relevant)
```

This ought to run close to O(N).

Here, I've implemented this into a fiddle, check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/miquelmartin/TdTv2/3/). You'll notice that the 4th example is odd: I haven't worked out the kinks because your problem definition doesn't state if you wanted the largest possible loop or any. In fact, you just wanted to know if there was a loop, which is known the moment you hit a light blue pixel.